# React child is not updating after after parent state changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've managed to add React elements dynamically depending on the content height [Add React elements dynamically depending on the content height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65367963/add-react-elements-dynamically-depending-on-the-content-height)

I've prepared a codesandbox to show this:

https://codesandbox.io/s/html-react-parser-forked-8pl3b

However, the problem I'm having right know is that the child component, which shows the actual article, is not reacting to the state updated of its parent. This can be tested just by clicking on the `Article 2` button.

Is it related to the usage of the reference? I can't figure out what is happening.

Comment: It's because you are not taking into consideration when the `html` prop changes. [You could do something like this](https://codesandbox.io/s/html-react-parser-forked-nv7tq?file=/src/index.js).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @tholle, but with that example you got rid of my previous effect, which implemented the feature I wanted.

Comment: Yes, I'm not saying you should replace it entirely, I was just pointing to what was missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the `Article` component has its own state. The `html` prop you pass in `const [article, setArticle] = React.useState(parse(html));` is the initial value and it's ignored when the prop changes.

You can use the useEffect hook to update the state when the prop's changed. You will also need to reset the `didInsertAds` state:

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
  setArticle(parse(html));
  setDidInsertAds(false);
}, [html]);
```

Comment: I tried that, but it's ignored if I keep my previous effect. It works if I remove the effect for adding the ads.

Comment: It's because `didInsertAds` is true all the time and you check it in the `useEffect` hook. If you reset it, it works fine.